# When is it equivalent to do a joint optimization over two variables in sequence over each variable?

Tags: optimization

Say I have a function $f(x,y)$. When is
$$\min_{x,y}f(x,y)=\min_x\min_y f(x,y)=\min_y\min_x f(x,y)$$ and what happens when there are constraints?

Comment: If the function f is convex, then the above are always equivalent.  As long as the constrains are linear constraints or linear inequality constraints, then the problem is convex and, again, the problems are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below equation is always true,
$$
\min_{x,y}f(x,y)=\min_x\min_y f(x,y)=\min_y\min_x f(x,y)
$$

Let's take any point $x_0, y_0$. The following is always true by definition of $\min$,
$$
f(x_0, y_0) \geq \ \min_y f(x_0, y) \geq \ \min_x\min_y f(x, y)
$$
Note that the above holds for any point $x_0, y_0$. What if $x_0, y_0 = \arg\min_{x, y} f(x, y)$?

$$
\implies \min_{x, y} f(x, y) \geq \ \min_x\min_y f(x, y)
$$

Let's prove the reverse direction for any point $x_0, y_0$,

$$
\min_{x, y} f(x, y) \leq f(x_0, y_0)
$$

The above holds for any $y_0$, What if $y_0 = \arg\min_{y} f(x_0, y)$?

$$
\min_{x, y} f(x, y) \leq \min_{y} f(x_0, y)
$$

The above holds for any $x_0$, What if $x_0 = \arg\min_{x} \arg\min_{y}f(x, y)$?

$$
\min_{x, y} f(x, y) \leq \min_x \min_{y} f(x, y)
$$

Combining both eqns. We get the required result.

Comment: So for this proof to work, you would need to assume that $f$ is convex in $x$, convex in $y$, and jointly convex in $x$ and $y$ right?

Comment: @Undertherainbow No we do not need any such assumptions. The statement is true for all families of functions. One can even replace the $\min$ by $\inf$ to make it even more robust.

Comment: Ah ok. This may not be generally applicable when there are constraints involving both variables right?

Comment: Actually it is applicable even with constraints. Let $X$ be the feasible space for $x$ and $Y$ be the feasible region for $y$. We can change all the equations to incorporate $x \in X$ and $y \in  Y$. For e.g. $\min_{x\in X, y\in Y}$

Comment: But what about when the constraints are not separable, e.g. $xy\ge1$?

Comment: Well, its still applicable but may not be useful. Say you have a constraint $\phi(x, y) \leq 0$, $\min_{y} f (x_0, y)$ becomes $\min_{y \ | \ \phi(x_0, y) \leq 0} f(x_0, y)$

Comment: To make it more clear. The result is valid on each and every part of domain. Hence, even when $\phi(x, y) \leq 0$ and $\phi$ is an implicit function of $x, y$, constraint region is still part of the domain and the result is valid.

Comment: Doesn't this result imply that when we don't need joint convexity in x and y to find a global optimum? We just need element-wise convexity?

Comment: Also you assume a unique minimum in each optimization right?